# Devolver JSON en metodos del Controller .NET

Tags: .net

Tengo mi plantilla de controlador en C# de la siguiente manera

```
using APIGESTION.EF;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RouteAttribute = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RouteAttribute;

namespace APIGESTION.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ClienteController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly gestionContext _context;

        public ClienteController(gestionContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Cliente
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Cliente>>> GetCliente()
        {
            return await _context.Clientes.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/ Cliente/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Cliente>> GetCliente(Guid id)
        {
            var Cliente = await _context.Clientes.FindAsync(id);

            if (Cliente == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Cliente;
        }

        // PUT: api/Cliente/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutCliente(Guid id, Cliente cliente)
        {
            if (id != cliente.IdCliente)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ClienteExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/cliente
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Cliente>> PostPais(Cliente cliente)
        {
            _context.Clientes.Add(cliente);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetCliente", new { id = cliente.IdCliente }, cliente);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Cliente/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Cliente>> DeleteCliente(Guid id)
        {
            var cliente = await _context.Clientes.FindAsync(id);
            if (cliente == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Clientes.Remove(cliente);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return cliente;
        }

        private bool ClienteExists(Guid id)
        {
            return _context.Clientes.Any(e => e.IdCliente == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Pero para trabajar con Angular en el frontend quisiera devolver JSON es lo mas practico me parece, pero bueno quisiera saber como hacer para que el metodo get o todos los que tienen respuestas tiren un JSON sea como objeto o como string

Edito:  En postman obtengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el caso es que mi aplicacion Angular devuelve los siguiente en la consola del navegador:
**core.js:6479 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()**

no se si me devuelve un objeto o que sucede.

Comment: Hola, por lo que veo tu proyecto es una REST Api, no tienes que procuparte por eso por defecto las repuestas son devueltas como json

Comment: De hecho logro obtenerlo por lo que se ve, pero no logro mostrar los datos

Comment: Lo que estás devolviendo es un JSON, solo que no estás recibiendo bien los datos en angular, tu error está en angular y no en tu web API, deberías mostrar cómo estás tratando de mostrar tu JSON en angular, también en tu API puedes agregar el OK, de está manera `return OK(return await _context.Clientes.ToListAsync());`

Answer (score 1):

La versión más básica que responde con a JsonResult es:

```
// GET: api/authors
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Get()
{
    return Json(_authorRepository.List());
}
```

Sin embargo, esto no ayudará con su problema porque no puede manejar explícitamente su propio código de respuesta

La forma de controlar los resultados del estado es devolver un, ActionResultque es donde puede aprovechar el StatusCodeResult tipo.

por ejemplo:

```
// GET: api/authors/search?namelike=foo
[HttpGet("Search")]
public IActionResult Search(string namelike)
{
    var result = _authorRepository.GetByNameSubstring(namelike);
    if (!result.Any())
    {
        return NotFound(namelike);
    }
    return Ok(result);
}

## Cosas extra

El problema con el que me encuentro con bastante frecuencia es que quería un control más granular sobre mi WebAPI en lugar de simplemente ir con la configuración predeterminada de la plantilla "Nuevo proyecto" en VS.

Asegurémonos de conocer algunos de los conceptos básicos ...
```

#### Paso 1: configura tu servicio

Para que su ASP.NET Core WebAPI responda con un objeto serializado JSON junto con el control total del código de estado, debe comenzar asegurándose de haber incluido el AddMvc()servicio en su ConfigureServicesmétodo que generalmente se encuentra en Startup.cs.

Es importante tener en cuenta que AddMvc()incluirá automáticamente el formateador de entrada / salida para JSON junto con la respuesta a otros tipos de solicitudes.

Si su proyecto requiere un control total y desea definir estrictamente sus servicios, por ejemplo, cómo se comportará su WebAPI ante varios tipos de solicitudes, incluidas application/json y no responder a otros tipos de solicitudes (como una solicitud estándar del navegador), puede definirlo manualmente con el siguiente código:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Build a customized MVC implementation, without using the default AddMvc(), instead use AddMvcCore().
    // https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

    services
        .AddMvcCore(options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsPermanent = true; // does not affect api requests
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true; // false by default
            //options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>();

            //remove these two below, but added so you know where to place them...
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new YourCustomOutputFormatter()); 
            options.InputFormatters.Add(new YourCustomInputFormatter());
        })
        //.AddApiExplorer()
        //.AddAuthorization()
        .AddFormatterMappings()
        //.AddCacheTagHelper()
        //.AddDataAnnotations()
        //.AddCors()
        .AddJsonFormatters(); // JSON, or you can build your own custom one (above)
}

Notará que también he incluido una forma de agregar sus propios formateadores de entrada / salida personalizados, en caso de que desee responder a otro formato de serialización (protobuf, thrift, etc.).

El fragmento de código anterior es principalmente un duplicado del AddMvc()método. Sin embargo, estamos implementando cada servicio "predeterminado" por nuestra cuenta definiendo todos y cada uno de los servicios en lugar de ir con el pre-enviado con la plantilla. He agregado el enlace del repositorio en el bloque de código, o puede consultarlo AddMvc() desde el repositorio de GitHub. .

Tenga en cuenta que hay algunas guías que intentarán resolver esto "deshaciendo" los valores predeterminados, en lugar de simplemente no implementarlo en primer lugar ... Si tiene en cuenta que ahora estamos trabajando con código abierto, este es un trabajo redundante. , mal código y francamente un viejo hábito que pronto desaparecerá.

La versión más básica que responde con a JsonResultes:

// GET: api/authors
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Get()
{
    return Json(_authorRepository.List());
}
Sin embargo, esto no ayudará con su problema porque no puede manejar explícitamente su propio código de respuesta.

La forma de controlar los resultados del estado es devolver un, ActionResultque es donde puede aprovechar el StatusCodeResulttipo.

por ejemplo:

// GET: api/authors/search?namelike=foo
[HttpGet("Search")]
public IActionResult Search(string namelike)
{
    var result = _authorRepository.GetByNameSubstring(namelike);
    if (!result.Any())
    {
        return NotFound(namelike);
    }
    return Ok(result);
}
Tenga en cuenta que los dos ejemplos anteriores provienen de una excelente guía disponible en la documentación de Microsoft: Formateo de datos de respuesta

Cosas extra
El problema con el que me encuentro con bastante frecuencia es que quería un control más granular sobre mi WebAPI en lugar de simplemente ir con la configuración predeterminada de la plantilla "Nuevo proyecto" en VS.

Asegurémonos de conocer algunos de los conceptos básicos ...

Paso 1: configura tu servicio
Para que su ASP.NET Core WebAPI responda con un objeto serializado JSON junto con el control total del código de estado, debe comenzar asegurándose de haber incluido el AddMvc()servicio en su ConfigureServicesmétodo que generalmente se encuentra en Startup.cs.

Es importante tener en cuenta que AddMvc()incluirá automáticamente el formateador de entrada / salida para JSON junto con la respuesta a otros tipos de solicitudes.

Si su proyecto requiere un control total y desea definir estrictamente sus servicios, por ejemplo, cómo se comportará su WebAPI ante varios tipos de solicitudes, incluidas application/jsony no responder a otros tipos de solicitudes (como una solicitud estándar del navegador), puede definirlo manualmente con el siguiente código:

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Build a customized MVC implementation, without using the default AddMvc(), instead use AddMvcCore().
    // https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

    services
        .AddMvcCore(options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsPermanent = true; // does not affect api requests
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true; // false by default
            //options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>();

            //remove these two below, but added so you know where to place them...
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new YourCustomOutputFormatter()); 
            options.InputFormatters.Add(new YourCustomInputFormatter());
        })
        //.AddApiExplorer()
        //.AddAuthorization()
        .AddFormatterMappings()
        //.AddCacheTagHelper()
        //.AddDataAnnotations()
        //.AddCors()
        .AddJsonFormatters(); // JSON, or you can build your own custom one (above)
}
```

Notará que también he incluido una forma de agregar sus propios formateadores de entrada / salida personalizados, en caso de que desee responder a otro formato de serialización (protobuf, thrift, etc.).

El fragmento de código anterior es principalmente un duplicado del AddMvc()método. Sin embargo, estamos implementando cada servicio "predeterminado" por nuestra cuenta definiendo todos y cada uno de los servicios en lugar de ir con el pre-enviado con la plantilla. He agregado el enlace del repositorio en el bloque de código, o puede consultarlo AddMvc() desde el repositorio de GitHub. .

Tenga en cuenta que hay algunas guías que intentarán resolver esto "deshaciendo" los valores predeterminados, en lugar de simplemente no implementarlo en primer lugar ... Si tiene en cuenta que ahora estamos trabajando con código abierto, este es un trabajo redundante. , mal código y francamente un viejo hábito que pronto desaparecerá.

#### Paso 2: crea un controlador

Voy a mostrarte uno realmente sencillo solo para resolver tu pregunta.

```
public class FooController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] Object item)
    {
        if (item == null) return BadRequest();

        var newItem = new Object(); // create the object to return
        if (newItem != null) return Ok(newItem);

        else return NotFound();
    }
}

### Paso 3: revisa tu Content-TypeyAccept

Debe asegurarse de que sus encabezados Content-Typey Accepten su solicitud estén configurados correctamente. En su caso (JSON), querrá configurarlo para que sea application/json.

Si desea que su WebAPI responda como JSON de forma predeterminada, independientemente de lo que especifique el encabezado de la solicitud, puede hacerlo de varias maneras .

Forma 1 Como se muestra en el artículo que recomendé anteriormente ( Formateo de datos de respuesta ), puede forzar un formato particular en el nivel de Controlador / Acción. Personalmente no me gusta este enfoque ... pero aquí está para completar:

Forzar un formato particular Si desea restringir los formatos de respuesta para una acción específica, puede aplicar el filtro [Produce]. El filtro [Produce] especifica los formatos de respuesta para una acción específica (o controlador). Como la mayoría de los filtros, esto se puede aplicar en la acción, el controlador o el ámbito global.
```

```
[Produces("application/json")]
public class AuthorsController
```

El filtro [Produces] obligará a todas las acciones dentro del AuthorsControllera devolver respuestas con formato JSON, incluso si se configuraron otros formateadores para la aplicación y el cliente proporcionó un Acceptencabezado solicitando un formato diferente disponible.

Forma 2 Mi método preferido es que WebAPI responda a todas las solicitudes con el formato solicitado. Sin embargo, en el caso de que no acepte el formato solicitado, recurra a un formato predeterminado (es decir, JSON)

Primero, deberá registrar eso en sus opciones (necesitamos reelaborar el comportamiento predeterminado, como se señaló anteriormente)

```
options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true; // false by default

Finalmente, simplemente reordenando la lista de los formateadores que se definieron en el generador de servicios, el servidor web tomará por defecto el formateador que usted coloca en la parte superior de la lista (es decir, la posición 0).
```